# Biblatex: Numeric in-text citations and Author-year in margin notes

Tags: biblatex, tufte-book

I am using the `tufte-book` class with `biblatex`, and I would like to have in-text citations to be numeric while also appearing as margin notes in a author-year style. To be more specific, I would like a citation in text to be like

> Lorem ipsum [12]

And a corresponding margin note like

> [12] Author et. al., (year).

I tried to do this with the `natbib` package, but I didn't manage to get a working result. This is why I switched to `biblatex` in the hope that its flexibility will make the task easier.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[nobib,notoc,nofonts,symmetric,justified,titlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose,citestyle=authoryear-ibid,autocite=footnote,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    
I would like citations to appear in-text as [1,2] in the main text, and have a margin note specify the author and year\marginnote{[1] \cite{one}.}\marginnote{[2] \cite{two}.}. In the bibliography, I would like to have the references sorted by their number (which is not the case here).
\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

And the corresponding `references.bib` file

```
@article{one,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {The ABC program system},
    journal = {Journal of Sci. Prog.},
    volume = {2},
    number = {1},
    pages = {5-10},
    year ={2021}
}


@book{two,
    title={A guide to Latex and Biblatex},
    author={Richard Doe},
    year={2000},
    publisher={Some Publisher}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

A good workaround is to redefine `\citeauthor` in such a way it shows numeric citation then cites author name and year as follows

```
\let \citeauthorX \citeauthor

\renewcommand{\citeauthor}[1]{\cite{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthorX{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1})}
```

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
    @book{kerr2018introduction,
        title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
        author={Julie Kerr},
        edition={1},
        year={2018},
        publisher={CRC Press}
    }
    @book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
        title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
        author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
        edition={1},
        year={2020},
        publisher={McGraw Hill}
    }
    @book{twidell2015renewable,
        title={Renewable Energy Resources},
        author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
        edition={3},
        year={2015},
        publisher={Routledge}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[nobib,justified,titlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\let \citeauthorX \citeauthor

\renewcommand{\citeauthor}[1]{\cite{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthorX{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1})}

\begin{document}
    
    I would like citations to appear in-text as \cite{kerr2018introduction,kanoğlu2010fundamentals,twidell2015renewable} in the main text, and have a margin note specify the author and year \marginnote{\citeauthor{kerr2018introduction}.}\marginnote{\citeauthor{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,twidell2015renewable}.}. In the bibliography, I would like to have the references sorted by their number.
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

[image]

Another variation is to define a custom command as follows

```
\let \citenumeric \cite
\newcommand{\citem}[1]{\citenumeric{#1}\marginnote{\citenumeric{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1})}}

\newcommand{\citemX}[2]{\citenumeric{#1,#2}%
    \marginnote{\citenumeric{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1})};\addspace%
    \marginnote{\citenumeric{#2}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#2}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#2})}%
}
```

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
    @book{kerr2018introduction,
        title={Introduction to Energy and Climate - Developing a Sustainable Environment},
        author={Julie Kerr},
        edition={1},
        year={2018},
        publisher={CRC Press}
    }
    @book{kanoğlu2010fundamentals,
        title={Fundamentals and Applications of Renewable Energy},
        author={Kanoğlu, Mehmet and Çengel, Yunus and Cimbala, John},
        edition={1},
        year={2020},
        publisher={McGraw Hill}
    }
    @book{twidell2015renewable,
        title={Renewable Energy Resources},
        author={Twidell, John and Weir, Tony},
        edition={3},
        year={2015},
        publisher={Routledge}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[nobib,justified,titlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% Modify citation style
\let \citenumeric \cite
\newcommand{\citem}[1]{\citenumeric{#1}\marginnote{\citenumeric{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1})}}

\newcommand{\citemX}[2]{\citenumeric{#1,#2}%
    \marginnote{\citenumeric{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1})};\addspace%
    \marginnote{\citenumeric{#2}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#2}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#2})}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    This citation is fine~\citem{kerr2018introduction}, but this one~\citemX{kanoğlu2010fundamentals}{twidell2015renewable} now appears as two separate entries in the margin note, while still having the [2, 3] combined numeric style in-text.
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This works well. However, I would like the margin citations to be split when one calls `\cite{one,two}` on two references, see my edit. Do you thing this is possible ?

Comment: I will accept this answer and post my edit as a separate question, thanks!