# Biblatex: \ifentryseen command not working

Tags: biblatex, tufte, tufte-book

Following a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620631/biblatex-numeric-in-text-citations-and-author-year-in-margin-notes/620677#620677), I defined a new `cite` command that does the following:

- If the entry has not been cited before, do an in-text `\citenumeric` and a margin note with the citation number, the author and year
- If the entry has been seen before, just do an in-text `\citenumeric`

I did this by using the `\ifentryseen` command of `biblatex`, with the `citetracker` option set to `true` and the `citereset` option set to `chapter`. However, it seems that the `\ifentryseen` command does not recognize already cited entries between separate paragraphs.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib,notoc,nofonts,symmetric,justified,titlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
citestyle=numeric,
hyperref=true,
doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, eprint=false,
giveninits=true,
abbreviate=false,
backend=biber,
citetracker=true,
citereset=chapter,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{references.bib}

\makeatletter

% Functional foreach construct 
% #1 - Function to call on each comma-separated item in #3
% #2 - Parameter to pass to function in #1 as first parameter
% #3 - Comma-separated list of items to pass as second parameter to function #1
\def\foreach#1#2{%
    \@test@foreach{#1}#2,\@end@token%
}

% Internal helper function - Eats one input
\def\@swallow#1{}

% Internal helper function - Checks the next character after #1 and #2 and 
% continues loop iteration if \@end@token is not found 
\def\@test@foreach#1{%
    \@ifnextchar\@end@token%
    {\@swallow}%
    {\@foreach{#1}}%
}

% Internal helper function - Calls #1{#2}{#3} and recurses
% The magic of splitting the third parameter occurs in the pattern matching of the \def
\def\@foreach#1#2,#3\@end@token{%
    #1{#2}%
    \@test@foreach{#1}#3\@end@token%
}

\makeatother



% Modify citation style
\let\citenumeric\cite
\newcommand{\citemargin}[1]{\marginnote{\citenumeric{#1}\addnbspace\citeauthor{#1}\addnbspace(\citeyear{#1}).}}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\ifentryseen{#1}{\citenumeric{#1}}{\citenumeric{#1}\foreach{\citemargin}{#1}} }


\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}


Two grouped citations should be split in separate margin notes  \cite{one,two}.
Now I will cite again \cite{one}, and the margin note should NOT appear.


\chapter{Second Chapter}

Now stuff is reset.
Two grouped citations should be split in separate margin notes  \cite{one,two}.
Now I will cite again \cite{one}, and the margin note should NOT appear.

However in a new paragraph it appears again \cite{one,two} and \cite{two}.

\end{document}
```

And `references.bib`:

```
@article{one,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {The ABC program system},
    journal = {Journal of Sci. Prog.},
    volume = {2},
    number = {1},
    pages = {5-10},
    year ={2021}
}


@book{two,
    title={A guide to Latex and Biblatex},
    author={Richard Doe},
    year={2000},
    publisher={Some Publisher}
}
```

Comment: you are using a local bibstyle and so your example can't be compiled.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. The local bibstyle had no influence on this problem. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ifentryseen` works as documented in the example. `\ifentryseen` takes a single `<key>` and checks if the entry corresponding to that key was seen before (taking into account resets etc.).

In the definition of `\cite` `\ifentryseen` is passed the first argument `#1`, which means that when you call `\cite{key1,key2}` you test `\ifciteseen{key1,key2}`. Since there is no entry called `key1,key2` this test always gives false. You need to make sure that you test only a single key (in your setup `\ifciteseen` should be inside a `\foreach`).

I would suggest a different approach. Usually it is better to try and solve these things by defining a `\...cite` command with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. Putting together several `\...cite` commands into one `\newcommand` can have undesirable implications for citation tracking (also in this case if one is not careful). Plus, `\DeclareCiteCommand` already comes with code to deal with multiple keys so that you don't even need a `\foreach`.

The idea here is to define two `\...cite` commands. One that prints the usual citations and collects the required citations for the margins and one that then prints the margin citations.

```
\documentclass[nobib,notoc,nofonts,symmetric,justified,titlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, eprint=false,
  giveninits=true,
  abbreviate=false,
  citetracker=true,
  citereset=chapter,
]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{cite:authoryear}{%
  \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \usebibmacro{cite}%
  }%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{##1}}%
  \printdate
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\makebibmarginnote}[1]{%
  \marginnote{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\maycite}[\makebibmarginnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:authoryear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@savedcites}{}

\newcommand*{\cbx@margcitewrap}[1]{%
  \global\let\cbx@savedcites\empty
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
  \cbx@savedcites
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\margincite}[\cbx@margcitewrap]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifciteseen
     {}
     {\xappto\cbx@savedcites{\noexpand\maycite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\margincites}[\cbx@margcitewrap]{\margincite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{margin}{\margincite}{\margincites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=margin}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

Two grouped citations should be split in separate margin notes \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}.
Now I will cite again \autocite{sigfridsson}, and the margin note should NOT appear.

\chapter{Second Chapter}
Now stuff is reset.
Two grouped citations should be split in separate margin notes  \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}.
Now I will cite again \autocite{sigfridsson}, and the margin note should NOT appear.

However in a new paragraph it appears again \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}.

\chapter{Third Chapter}
Now stuff is reset.
Two grouped citations should be split in separate margin notes  \autocites{sigfridsson}{worman}.
Now I will cite again \autocite{sigfridsson}, and the margin note should NOT appear.

However in a new paragraph it appears again \autocites{sigfridsson}{worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Second chapter with two margin notes.]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I did not know about the `\DeclareCiteCommand` commands.